# RegEx - How To Insert String Before File Extension

Tags: php, regex

How would I insert "_thumb" into files that are being dyanmically generated.

For example, I have a site that allows users to upload an image. The script takes the image, optimizes it and saves to file. How would I make it insert the string "_thumb" for the optimized image?

I'm currently saving 1 version of the otpimized file. 
ch-1268312613-photo.jpg

I want to save the original as the above string, but want to append, "_thumb" like the following string
ch-1268312613-photo_thumb.jpg

Answer (score 45, accepted):

No need to use regex. This will do it:

```
$extension_pos = strrpos($filename, '.'); // find position of the last dot, so where the extension starts
$thumb = substr($filename, 0, $extension_pos) . '_thumb' . substr($filename, $extension_pos);
```

Comment: wont for such thing as `.tar.gz`

Comment: @Skyzer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75505259/5049864

Answer (score 20):

Rather than take the regular expression route (or other crude string manipulation) perhaps some filename-related functions might be easier to live with: namely pathinfo (to get the file extension) and basename (to get the filename minus extension).

```
$ext   = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$thumb = basename($filename, ".$ext") . '_thumb.' . $ext;
```

*Edit*: @tanascius sorry for the very similar answer, guess I should've checked the little pop-up whilst writing this (it took a while, I got distracted).

Comment: Not quite worthy of a new answer but this can be one line: `pathinfo($filename,8) . '_thumb.' . pathinfo($filename,4);`

Answer (score 5):

Why do you want to use a RegEx? Is the extension always `.jpg` and is there only one extension? Maybe you can replace it by `_thumb.jpg`?

If it is not that simple, you can use a function like [pathinfo](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_pathinfo.asp) to extract the basename + extension and do a replace there. That is working without a regex, too, which might be overkill here:

```
$info = pathinfo( $file );
$no_extension =  basename( $file, '.'.$info['extension'] );
echo $no_extension.'_thumb.'.$info['extension']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 preg_replace("/(\w+)\.(\w+)/","'\\1_thumb.\\2'","test.jpg");
```

I think that using a regexp is far more speed effective AND really better for 
flexibility.

But I admit Chad's solution is elegant and effective

Comment: There are a couple things wrong with this. You didn't escape the period in the pattern, so that will match any character at all. Also, `\w` does not cover all possible filename characters.

Comment: True, because I didn't mark it as code so \. was interpreted like . 
And True again but does the filesystem has the right to use any char, I bet no

Comment: Good one! But I'd do it like so: preg_replace("/^(.+)\.(\w+)$/","\\1_thumb.\\2",$filename); -- check with "https://local.server.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/filename.jpg"

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you only have the occurrence of ".jpg" once in the string, you can do a [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) instead of regex

```
$filename = str_replace(".jpg", "_thumb.jpg", $filename);
```

or even better, [`substr_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) to just insert the string somewhere in the middle:

```
$filename = substr_replace($filename, '_thumb', -4, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "ch-1268312613-photo.jpg";
print preg_replace("/\.jpg$/i","_thumb.jpg",$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fast and can correct to show it,

```
/**
* 增加後綴字至檔名後方
* Add suffix to a file name
* 
* @example suffixFileName("test.tar.gz", '_new'); //it will retrun "test.tar_new.gz"
* @version 2023.06.20 Jwu
* @param string $fullPath filename
* @param string $suffix   insert String Before File Extension
*
* @return string new file path
*/
function suffixFileName($fullPath, $suffix = "_thumb"){
    $pos = strrpos($fullPath, ".");
    if(substr($fullPath, -1) == '.'){
        $pos = strrpos(substr($fullPath, 0, $pos), ".");
    }
    if ($pos === false) {
        return $fullPath . $suffix;
    }
    //$filenameWithoutExt = substr($fileName, 0, -(strlen($pos) + 2));
    return substr_replace($fullPath, $suffix, $pos, 0);
}
```

Test Demo:

```
// Unit Test
function output($n){
    print_r($n);
    print_r('<br>');
    print_r(suffixFileName($n, "_thumb"));
    print_r('<hr>');
}
$testFiles = array(
    'C:\Jwu\TestPictures\sample.jpg',
    'http://Jwu/TestPictures/sample.jpg',
    'TestPictures\this.is.a.jpg',
    'sample.tar.gz',
    '1.jpg',
    '.jpg',
    'recent.image.jpg.',
    'image.gift.1234.gif'
);
array_map('output', $testFiles);
```

Output:

```
C:\Jwu\TestPictures\sample.jpg
C:\Jwu\TestPictures\sample_thumb.jpg

http://Jwu/TestPictures/sample.jpg
http://Jwu/TestPictures/sample_thumb.jpg

TestPictures\this.is.a.jpg
TestPictures\this.is.a_thumb.jpg

sample.tar.gz
sample.tar_thumb.gz

1.jpg
1_thumb.jpg

.jpg
_thumb.jpg

recent.image.jpg.
recent.image_thumb.jpg.

image.gift.1234.gif
image.gift.1234_thumb.gif
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are wanting to inject your substring just before the first occurring dot, `preg_replace()` is a direct technique. Using a start of string anchor and a negated character class in the pattern, there can only be one replacement at most.  Because `\K` restarts the fullstring match, the replacement string only replaces the literal dot that is matched.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1KCbA))

```
$strings = [
    "ch-1268312613-photo.jpg",
    "foo.inc.php",
    ".htaccess",
    "no_ext",
];

var_export(
    preg_replace(
        '~^[^.]*\K\.~',
        '_thumb.',
        $strings
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'ch-1268312613-photo_thumb.jpg',
  1 => 'foo_thumb.inc.php',
  2 => '_thumb.htaccess',
  3 => 'no_ext',
)
```

---

Just for fun, these 2-call techniques also work: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1f69I))

```
echo implode('_thumb.', explode('.', $string, 2));
```

and

```
echo implode('_thumb', sscanf($string, '%[^.]%s'));
```

Comment: Any comment to accompany the dv on my answer which is proven to work correctly?