# Add suffix to a file name

Tags: php, regex

```
$config['file_name'] = preg_replace('/(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)/', '_thumb$1', $filename);
```

Basically I want `filename.jpg` to become `filename_thumb.jpg`

I don't understand why but the extension is being repeated twice. (filename.jpg.jpg).

**Edit** This does work, I have other problems in my code.

Comment: your code works as expected: echo preg_replace('/(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)/', '_thumb$1', 'index.gif'); ps: add $ to the end of the expression.

Comment: See here for a solution without regex:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429611/regex-how-to-insert-string-before-file-extension

Comment: [`preg_replace('/(?=\.)/', '_thumb', $filename, 1);`](https://3v4l.org/hiZLi) looks fine to me.

Comment: Ah, I agree with Matthew, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2429611/2943403

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should work.

```
echo preg_replace('/(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)/', '_thumb$1', "filename.jpg");
```

gives `filename_thumb.jpg`.

In any case, use the expression `'/(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$/'` instead (better, don't use parentheses and replace $1 with $0), so that it only matches the string if it's on the end.

Comment: without parentheses he will be not able to specify $ without copy-pasting it for each extension

Comment: @zerkms Good point. But he can use `(?:)` instead. There's really no need to use a capture group.

Answer (score 11):

The best way to do it would probably be...

```
$filename_ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$filename = preg_replace('/^(.*)\.' . $filename_ext . '$/', '$1_thumb.' . $filename_ext, $filename);
```

I justed tested it, with `$filename = 'path/to/something.jpg';` and the output was `path/to/something_thumb.jpg`.

I say the *best way* because generally using PHP's inbuilt functions are better. This also allows for all file extensions that PHP can handle (being string splitting, it should be all).

Comment: What about extensions that contain characters that have meaning in regular expressions?..

Comment: @Artefacto True, [but which ones do](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)? Can't think of any of the top of my head... I'm sure there are some edge cases though.

Comment: @Artefacto I just thought of `tar.gz`... [PHP returns](http://codepad.org/9FtqvjXn) `gz` only. So I guess that might not be correct from an extension point of view, but correct if finding characters following the last occurrence of a period.

Comment: @Artefacto Which extensions contain brackets though?

Comment: @alex how is `gz` not correct for a file named `foo.tar.gz`; is it not a gzipped file?

Comment: @alex https://stackoverflow.com/a/75505259/5049864 About tar.gz

Answer (score 2):

Maybe would be best to use PHP's in build methods such as `pathinfo` and `basename`.
this would handle all kind of files including ones without extension

```
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$baseName = basename($filename, ".{$extension}");
$newName = "{$baseName}_thumb.{$extension}";
```

Answer (score 0):

shortest & fastest

```
$img = '/path/to/picture.jpg';
$thumb = substr_replace( $img, '_thumb.', strrpos($img, '.'), 1);
echo $thumb;
// /path/to/picture_thumb.jpg
```

Comment: Some educational explanation is better than no educational explanation.