# php, add string to filename

Tags: php, html

I have two variable:

```
$lang = hu

$image = image.jpg
```

How to replace image.jpg to image_hu.jpg in php? Maybe with str_replace? But how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) would work well:

```
$new_str = preg_replace('/(\.[^.]+)$/', sprintf('%s$1', $lang), $image);
```

Comment: Note - this code will only work for JPGs. For a more universal method, try `explode()`.

Comment: @Duthcie432: Or you could just change the regexp from '/\.jpg$/' to '/\.[a-z0-9]+$/' and it will work for all file extensions.

Comment: Fair enough. What if the filename has more than one `.` like `image.test.png`

Comment: I determine the filename and the extension, so the first example works for me. I edited the question: $lang is without the '_' character. I modified the first example, that is working, but what I need to modify, when I want to use the more universal version  '/\.jpg$/' to '/\.[a-z0-9]+$/'

Comment: `str_replace( '.', '_hu.', $image )`

Comment: @Galen - again this only works for files with one `.`. So in that respect it works just as well as accepted answer

Comment: @Dutchie432 - right, he said he controls the filename, so both answers will work. I just prefer to not use regexs if i dont have to.

Answer (score 6):

this method will work for any file type and with image names that have more than one period. ([DEMO](http://codepad.org/4jTPF5dv))

**Code**

```
<?php 

    echo merge('image.test.1234.gif', '_en');

    function merge($file, $language){
        $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $filename = str_replace('.'.$ext, '', $file).$language.'.'.$ext;
        return ($filename);
    }
?>
```

**Result**

```
image.test.1234_en.gif
```

Comment: This would fail if for some reason the file name had an extra dot in it like: `recent.image.jpg`. The result would be `recent_hu.image.jpg`

Comment: Sorry you must have caught me in between updates. Updated to work properly now.

Comment: this will fail if the filename has $ext inside of the name: `'image.gift.1234.gif'`

Comment: @stevecomrie, Try this, fast and can correct to show it, https://stackoverflow.com/a/75505259/5049864

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to use the built in function [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to separate the file extension from the filename.

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('image.jpg');

$final = $path_parts['filename'] . $lang . '.' . $path_parts['extension'];
```

Comment: I think this is actually a much more readable solution than any of the regex ones based ones.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following:

```
$new_str = preg_replace( '/^(.*?)\.(\w+)$/', '${1}$lang.${2}', $image );
```

That way your code would still work for JPG/gif/jpeg/PNG/etc